# Footnote in longtable

Tags: latex, tabular

How to add footer in tables that occupy more than 2 pages in LaTeX? I have tried in many ways but none have worked, clicking on the marker directs me to another place.

Comment: Hello! Non-programming related questions abut LaTeX are better suited for [TeX & LaTeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please add a [mre] so we can what you've already tried. Please also include a sketch how the result should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Yuor question is not very clear to me but [`longtable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) behaves well respect to both the table *footers* (`\endfoot`, `\endlastfoot`) and the *footnotes* (`\footnote`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{c|c}
\caption{Caption of the table.}
\label{tab:long}\\
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}\\
\hline
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B}\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}\\
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
1\footnote{Blah.} & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\
1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\
1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\
1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\
1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\
1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\footnote{Blah blah.}\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\
1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\
1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\
1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\
1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\
1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\
1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\\1 & 2\footnote{Blah blah blah.}\\1 & 2\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```